# What are the use cases for IntStream?

Tags: java, lambda

I've written some code that creates a `List<Integer>` from a `Stream<List<Integer>>` like so:

```
List<Integer> abc = stream.flatMap(e -> e.stream()).
    collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I'm interested how to use IntStream. I thought I could do

```
List<Integer> abc = stream.flatMapToInt(e -> e.stream()).
    collect(Collectors.toList());
```

using `flatMapToInt` to give me an IntStream that the collector would collect, but I get a compilation error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collector<Object,?,List<Object>> to Supplier<R>
```

What is an IntStream, how is it different to a regular stream, and when would you use it?

Comment: Here's the javadoc, which answers your question: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You more-or-less use `IntStream` when you have intermediate or terminal operations that don't require boxing, and frequently when you want arithmetic results.  For example, you might write

```
students.stream().mapToInt(Student::getTestScore).average()
```

Generally, you'd want to use it when your intermediate results are not boxed -- not the case with a `List<List<Integer>>` and either you're mapping the unboxed result to a boxed thing with `mapToObj`, or doing something arithmeticky with it like `average()` here.

It doesn't buy you anything except possibly pain for this use case, which doesn't actually care that the list contents are `Integer`s; you're not using anything about integers here.